# Entity Framework trying to insert existing records into database

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I have two entities `Result` and `Rule`. `Result` contains a `Rule`. I fetch a `Rule` from the database and try to assign it to multiple `Result` objects, using a different context.

When I try to do `context.SaveChanges()`, Entity Framework tries to insert the `Rule` - that already exists - into the database again. I've tried different combinations of attaching and changing state for the past few hours and I'm at a loss.

What could be causing this behavior?

Entities:

```
public class Result
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int RuleId { get; set; }
    public Rule Rule { get; set; }
}

public class Rule
{
    public Rule()
    {
        Results = new HashSet<Result>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings:

```
public class ResultMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Result>
{
    public ResultMapping()
    {
        ToTable("Result");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        HasRequired(x => x.Rule)
            .WithMany(y => y.Results)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.RuleId);
    }
}

public class RuleMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Rule>
{
    public RuleMapping()
    {
        ToTable("Rule");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}
```

Assignment:

```
private void DoStuff(ICollection<Result> results, ScanResultContext context)
{
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        var rule = RulesFromAnotherContextDictonary[result.Rule.Identifier];

        // None of this makes it work
        context.Set<Rule>().Attach(rule);
        result.Rule = null;
        result.RuleId = rule.Id;

        context.Set<Result>().Add(result);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
private void DoStuff(ICollection<Result> results, ScanResultContext context)
{
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        var rule = RulesFromAnotherContextDictonary[result.Rule.Identifier];

        // None of this makes it work
        context.Set<Rule>().Attach(rule);
        result.Rule = rule;
        context.Set<Result>().Add(result);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Attempt 3:

```
private void DoStuff(ICollection<Result> results, ScanResultContext context)
{
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        var rule = context.Set<Rule>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Identifier == result.Rule.Identifier);

        if (rule != null)
            result.Rule = rule;

        context.Set<Result>().Add(result);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Try `result.Rule = rule;`, although *only* `result.RuleId = rule.Id;` should be OK too. Probably even `result.RuleId = result.Rule.Identifier;`, so you don't have to fetch the rule at all.

Comment: Why do you need to `attach` or `add` rules? if you are adding RESULTS to db, just set `RuleId`?

Comment: *using a different context*, no, please, don't.. use one db context for a single transaction..

Comment: @BagusTesa just assume the rule to be the result of a user selection... sometimes the input data that will be used in a transaction are way older than the current context and it's perfectly valid to work with them. Ofcourse it is possible to reload the rule from context by `Id`, but the other option (only setting the `RuleId`) is a valid choice as well.

Comment: Jeff, are you sure that all of your attempts lead to the same result (attempted re-insert)? Are you sure that your context is not already corrupted before you start the modification?